# Using Microsoft 600 Wired Keyboard Fn keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

At work, I have a simple [Microsoft wired 600 keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-gb/products/keyboards/wired-keyboard-600/anb-00006) which has four keys (<kbd>F5</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>) with blue symbols which look like they can be 'launched' in combination with the (blue) <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. However, pressing them in combination doesn't do anything either while on the desktop nor in an application (Chrome, Excel). Can anyone suggest:

1. What the keys are for?
2. How to get them to start working?

See the keyboard photo below

[image: keyboard photo].

When I plugged the keyboard in, Windows said that the device was installed successfully, so I don't expect additional drivers are required, though I don't have admin privileges, should more installs be required.

OS: Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1, 64bit

Comment: do you have a clearer image of those keys?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - uploaded photo, updated post

Answer (score 0):

There are many keyboards that offer special functionality such as media player Play, Stop,... or browser Home, New Tab,...

In order to have full functionality you need to download and install the specific driver. Windows can detect and install only a generic driver that can provide regular functionality.

In your case the specific driver can be found for download [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=849755)

Answer (score 0):

Still there is no driver for Windows 7 (64 bit) supporting the blue keys available in Microsoft. Also, those cannot be supported in Java, as Java is not able to identify them correctly (although Java can see some of them pressed/releassed).

Tomek

Answer (score 0):

For 64 bit users you can download the Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600 driver here:

https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-gb/d/wired-keyboard-600