# What does the FN + F6 -button do on the MS keyboard 600?

Tags: keyboard

[image: image of keyboard]

From this question: [Using Microsoft 600 Wired Keyboard Fn keys](https://superuser.com/questions/1245724/using-microsoft-600-wired-keyboard-fn-keys)

What is the purpose of the Fn+F6 button on the MS keyboard 600? It has a circle with 3 dots around it. Closest thing that it resembles for me is the recycle sign. It does nothing when I press it.

1. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> opens start menu search
2. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> connects to wireless screens and audio
3. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> opens system settings

Comment: I'm missing a few pieces of the puzzle but https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/6w4j21/can_anyone_tell_me_what_the_fnf6_key_does_on_the/ suggests it might be an obsolete hotkey for the old windows 8 sharing charm

Comment: yes this looks right. ok so useless button

Comment: Yes indeed. https://youtu.be/Ug-6yjQE5Hs?t=34 has a pic of the box, and those four are labeled "Windows 8 shortcut keys". According to [desktority.net](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Microsoft_Wired_Keyboard_600) specs used to call them "Windows 8 Charms keys".

Comment: LOL I just now noticed my old MS Sculpt kbd has them as well :-D Pressing FN+F6 produces keycode sequence 56 press - 125pr - 191pr - 56 release - 125rel - 191rel. I guess it could be mapped to do something useful...

Comment: I mapped mine to type Trinity because it looks like a trinity symbol. Wanted to trick someone. But forgot about it. Pressed it this morning while I was in gmail and the side panel opened because Shift+T opens Tasks. Seriously thought for a moment gmail implemented the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft apparently used that for the share 'charm' on windows 8 - its a bit of a stretch but

This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/6w4j21/can_anyone_tell_me_what_the_fnf6_key_does_on_the/) says that the surface 3 keyboard's <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> is the hotkey for the obsolete windows share charm. Cross referencing that with [Scott Hanselman's blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/surface-pro-3-initial-impressions), the SP3 has the symbol you refer to.

[image]

This [smart company article](https://www.fastcompany.com/3031872/why-isnt-there-a-standard-share-button) confirms that its the 'period correct' sharing icon for windows 8.

[image]

Though *clearly* its popularity was overstated.

Windows 11 uses very different iconography

[image]

But essentially yes - its a 'useless' short cut for an obsolete feature that's no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the purpose of the Fn+F6 button on the MS keyboard 600?

It's a share key, whatever that is:

> The multimedia keys at the top are play/pause and volume up/down and mute, a calculator key is always handy above the Num Lock and 4 Fn keys on F5/search, F6/share, F7/notify, F8/set.

Source: [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600 reviews - LDLC customers comments and tests](https://www.ldlc.com/en/reviews/PB00085130.html)

It should be possible to remap it to something else ...